# How to launch application from USB mac osx?

Tags: macos

I am working on a mac application. The application needs to run from the removable device. Also, I like to know if it would be possible to make a copy of RAM (that is being used at that time)?

Thanks!!

Comment: In the time it took you to log in to StackOverflow, you could have tried to launch an application from a USB device. I suggest you try it!

Answer (score 1):

> I am working on a mac application. The application needs to run from the removable device.

So put the application on the removable device, then? Note that there is no way to make it run without user interaction ("autorun").

> Also, I like to know if it would be possible to make a copy of RAM (that is being used at that time)?

This doesn't really make much sense. Your application is free to make a copy of its own memory of course, but this is unlikely to be very interesting. You cannot read the contents of other applications' memory, however, without some pretty deep magic (and administrator authorization).

What on earth are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am working on an investigating tool which has to pull some information of investigator's interest from a mac. Yeah, I know that an application can be run from USB. But I would like to know if anything specifically needs to be done for an application which can only run from a removable device.

Comment: So, there is no possibility of copying the entire RAM of the system even with administrator authorization?

Comment: It's not impossible, but it's also not trivial. I suspect you'd have to load a kext to make it happen.